# R termplot: Plot spline curve at level of actual data points

Tags: r, spline

In R, stats::termplot can be used to plot the partial residuals for a spline term from a regression.  When there is a single predictor term, it would be useful to plot this partial residual curve adjusted so that the y values correspond to the actual data values.  E. g.

```
library("splines")
a <- c(0:5, 7, 10)
b <- c(0, 2.7, 28.1, 48.3, 37.5, 42.3, 37.4, 32.3)
model1 <- lm(b ~ bs(a))
model1
termplot(model1, partial.resid = TRUE, col.res = 'red', ylim = c(-40, 40))
points(a, b)
```

This produces the following figure:
[image]

The spline curve tracks the partial.residuals accurately, but the residual y values are offset from the actual y values by a constant value.  I don't know how to calculate the offset, or how to adjust the height of the spline curve so that it reflects the actual predicted values at the x points.  I might have thought that this was the intercept value.  But it isn't.  Can anyone tell me how I can determine this offset value?  Is there a way within the termplot function to adjust the height of the spline curve?
Thanks in advance for any help that you can give me.
Larry Hunsicker